# Given a random variable $Y=Ab+DX$. How do you compute the covariance of $Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, random-variables, means

Given a random variable $Y=Ab+DX$ where $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. For a fixed $b$ and $D,A$. How do you compute the covariance of $Y$?

I know that $\mu_{Y} = Ab + D\mu$ and $Cov(Y) = E\{(Y-\mu_{Y})(Y-\mu_{Y})^{T}\}$.

In my notes I have that $(Y-\mu_{Y}) = D(X-\mu)$ which I don't understand. Shoudln't it be $(Y-\mu_{Y}) = (Y-D(X-\mu))$? Or is it supposed to be $E\{(Y-\mu_{Y})\} = D(X-\mu)$?

I also don't understand why $XX^{T} = \Sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that
$$
(Y-\mu_Y)=Ab+DX-Ab-D\mu=D(X-\mu).
$$
The covariance matrix is given by
\begin{align*}
\operatorname E[(Y-\mu_Y)(Y-\mu_Y)^{\mathrm T}]
&=\operatorname E[D(X-\mu)(D(X-\mu))^{\mathrm T}]\\
&=\operatorname E[D(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^{\mathrm T}D^{\mathrm T}]\\
&=D\operatorname E[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^{\mathrm T}]D^{\mathrm T}\\
&=D\Sigma D^{\mathrm T}.
\end{align*}
$XX^{\mathrm T}$ is random and $\Sigma$ is just a matrix. It does not make sense to write $XX^{\mathrm T}=\Sigma$.